# Fisher information matrix for model based design of experiments

Tags: experiment-design, fisher-information, hessian

I'm trying to use the Fisher information matrix and D-optimal design for model-based experiment selection, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing or interpreting it correctly.

I begin with the values of parameters and the associated covariance matrix with the goal of finding the most informative experiment through changing two initial conditions. Before implementing a general optimization algorithm, I wanted to see how the D-optimal would perform using a factorial design (10^2 simulations (10 values for each initial condition)).

I'm calculating the Hessian at each experimental condition, written as:

$$
[H_{\theta}]_{kl} = \sum^{N_{m}}_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sigma{}_{i}^{2}}\Bigg(\frac{\partial^{2}\hat{y}_{i}}{\partial{}\theta{}_{k}\partial{}\theta{}_{l}}\Bigg)
$$

where $N_{m}$ is the number of data points in the output, $\sigma{}_{i}$ is the predicted standard deviation of the output (assumed constant),  $\hat{y}_{i}$ is the value of the predicted output, and $\theta{}$ are the parameters of interest.

When I calculate the Hessian at each of the experimental conditions, the eigenvalues (as well as the determinant) are a mixture of positive and negative values. The absolute value of the determinant seems to correlate with the "best" experiment, but I'm not sure if this is a coincidence or not.

Is this result an indication that the methodology won't work? Or am I just defining the equation incorrectly? Or is it a reasonable result?