# Does the Fisher information matrix have to be convex when assessing an optimal criteria?

Tags: experiment-design, fisher-information, differential-equations

I've reached a local minimum for a proposed model using a set of experimental data (positive definite Hessian) and want to select an additional experiment that will reduce the parameter uncertainties (through model-based design of experiments).

[When I calculate the Fisher information matrix at proposed experimental conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533389/fisher-information-matrix-for-model-based-design-of-experimentshttps://), I get a Hessian with negative and positive eigenvalues.

Is this result an indication that the methodology won't work? It seems like the absolute value of the determinant (d-optimum) correlates with the "optimal" experiment, but I'm not sure if this is just a coincidence.

Comment: The (population) Fisher information matrix is always positive semidefinite because  it is defined as the covariance matrix of the score function.

Comment: @passerby51 Might be a naive follow up, but how would you define the score function based only on the simulated output? Is the way I specified it in the previous post accurate. And if it is correct and it isn't positive semidefinite, is that an indication that the equation is written wrong or does it mean the method isn't applicable in this case>

Comment: The Fisher information matrix cannot have negative eigenvalues, so something went wrong. Bur without more details we cannot diagnose it